# Call function from array jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My code:

```
$('.play').click(function () {
 //HERE IS ACTION
//I WANT TO CALL RANDOM FUNCTION FROM ARRAY
        });


function testone(){
alert("WORK F 1111");
}

function testtwo(){
alert("WORK F 2222");
}


function testthree(){
alert("WORK F 3333");
}


var testarray = ["testone();","testtwo();","testthree();"]
```

Anyone can help me with this, i don't know how to call function from array.
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain that more? And example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference the actual function, don't use strings, and it's quite easy

```
$('.play').click(function () {
   var random = testarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * testarray.length)];

    random();
});


function testone(){
    alert("WORK F 1111");
}

function testtwo(){
    alert("WORK F 2222");
}

function testthree(){
    alert("WORK F 3333");
}

var testarray = [testone, testtwo, testthree];
```

```js
$('.play').click(function () {
   var random = testarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * testarray.length)];

    random();
});


function testone(){
    alert("WORK F 1111");
}

function testtwo(){
    alert("WORK F 2222");
}

function testthree(){
    alert("WORK F 3333");
}

var testarray = [testone, testtwo, testthree];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="play">Click Me</div>
```